# Angular 4: importing a javascript module gives multiple errors

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

I have a javascript module (ie IIFE file) that I wish to use in Angular 4
I have done this:

```js
declare var DataRequestsToHost: any;

import * as DataRequestsToHost from '../../../../hostScripts/DataRequestsToHost';
```

but the `import` statement errors with:

> ```
> Build:Module '../../../../hostScripts/DataRequestsToHost' was resolved to 'hostScripts/DataRequestsToHost.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
> ```

So I add `allowJs = true` to tsconfig.json

Then in Visual studio I get 2 errors:

> ```
> Build:Cannot write file 'D:/VS2017Projects/ThirdPartyExam1/ThirdPartyExam1/systemjs.config.js'
> because it would overwrite input file.
>
> Build:Cannot write file 'D:/VS2017Projects/ThirdPartyExam1/ThirdPartyExam1/hostScripts/DataRequestsToHost.js'
> because it would overwrite input file.
> ```

both "hostsscripts" and "systemjs.config" are in the tsconfig.json's `exclude` section

How can I get around this issue ?

regards

GregJF